# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar siempre la misma tabla cuando puso Anterior o Siguiente?

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando con un plugin de mantis bt llamado *Taskodrome* (*no sé si alguien ha trabajado con esto*).

Bien, mi duda es: como puedo hacer que al pulsar siguiente o anterior (*ahora adjunto captura del programa*), se mantenga en el mismo input radio, ya que el ancla (#dg,#sg y #rg respectivamente) siempre se dirige a la misma dirección, Assignment board, aunque estés en status o relationship siempre por defecto te redirige al mismo lado. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver este problema.

El programa es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
 $f_page_number = gpc_get_int('page_number',1);
      $t_per_page = null;
      $t_bug_count = null;
      $t_page_count = null;

      $rows = filter_get_bug_rows( $f_page_number, $t_per_page, $t_page_count, $t_bug_count, null, null, null, true );

    print '<section class="tabs">

    <input type="radio" id="radio_dg" name="group" >
    <input type="radio" id="radio_sg" name="group" >
    <input type="radio" id="radio_rg" name="group" >
    

    <label id="label_dg" class="radio_label" for="radio_dg" >' . plugin_lang_get("assignment_board") . '</label>
    <label id="label_sg" class="radio_label" for="radio_sg" >' . plugin_lang_get("status_board") . '</label>
    <label id="label_rg" class="radio_label" for="radio_rg" >' . plugin_lang_get("relationship_board") . '</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_version">
    <label id="label_version" class="checkbox_label" for="checkbox_version">' . plugin_lang_get("empty_version_label") . '</label>';

    print '<div>';
        if($f_page_number){
            if($f_page_number > 1){
                ?>
                <a href="/mantis/plugin.php?page=Taskodrome/main&page_number=<?php echo $f_page_number -1;?>#dg"><button class="radio_label">Anterior</button></a>
                <?php

            }else{
                print '<a href="#"><button disabled>Anterior</button></a>';
            }
        }else{
            print '<a href="#"><button disabled>Anterior</button>';
        }

        if($f_page_number){
            if((($f_page_number -1 ) * $t_per_page) < $rows){
                ?>
                <a href="/mantis/plugin.php?page=Taskodrome/main&page_number=<?php echo $f_page_number + 1;?>#dg"><button class="radio_label">Siguiente</button></a>
                <?php

            }else{
                print '<a href="#"><button disabled>Siguiente</button></a>';
            }
        }else{
            print '<a href="/mantis/plugin.php?page=Taskodrome/main&page_number=2"><button>Siguiente</button></a>';

        }
    print '</div>';

    print '<div class="tabs_cont">';
    print'<div id="tab_c1" class="grid">';

    print '<canvas id="canvas_dv">
        </canvas>
        </div>
     ';

    print '<div id="tab_c2" class="grid">
    <canvas id="canvas_st">
    </canvas>
    </div>
    ';

    print '<div id="tab_c3" class="grid">
    <canvas id="canvas_rl">
    </canvas>
    </div>
    ';

    print '</div>
    </section>
    ';


  }
```

Comment: Te falta asignar el valor del radio, luego obtenerlo, agregarlo a los enlaces y, supongo, también usarlo para filtrar.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Con respecto a asignar al valor, te referirás al atributo value, pero luego se puede obtener mediante post o como?